# How do I get my FreeNAS started after a restart

Tags: truenas, ipmi, startup

My NAS appliance (a FreeNAS MINI) wasn't responding today. (users couldn't access their network shares)

Server IP addresses are assigned by DHCP. I access by host names.

So, I tried connecting to the admin page, but the entire server wouldn't respond  (it was responding yesterday or the day before) (the problem was DNS didn't resolve)

I connected to it via IPMI, and I noticed that it was running hot (93), so I shut it down, and cleaned it out (it had some dust from sitting in the corner).

But it still won't start back up. I can connect to IPMI, and now there isn't a CPU temperature (ASRock Rack is the IPMI UI), but all of the sensor monitors are green on the dashboard.

So right now, I'm not sure what to do next, there's a few logs in the IPMI. There's also Java access to the consoles, but I don't believe there's a secure way of running Java access? (Or is there?)

Comment: Because I've got IPMI access, it /feels/ like a serverfault question, but if you guys think it belongs better in superuser.com, I'm cool with a migration.

Comment: Can you see the IP it has now ? I would put a DHCP reservation in the minimum to prevent such problem

Comment: @yagmoth555 I can see the IP of the IPMI, but not of the server tiself.

Comment: Does the NIC's led status flash or not behind the NAS ?